# problem in flutter widgets not generating fully in vscode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

whenever to generate and select widgets for example Text widget it comes incomplete like "**Text**" instead of "**Text()**". i have tried to uninstall and reinstall Vscode but it is still doing the same. i am using vscode 1.52.1

Comment: You've installed the Flutter extension?  Is the analyzer running?  And what do you mean "generate"?

Comment: Check your settings for Dart. You probably have preview lsp turned on. Try turning it off.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're probably using the LSP Preview which didn't have this functionality until recently. If you're using a recent dev build, you should be able to get it back by enabling the [`dart.completeFunctionCalls`](https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-17/#lsp-complete-function-calls) setting.

> [#2823](https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-17/#lsp-complete-function-calls): A new setting dart.completeFunctionCalls will cause code completion on functions/methods to include parentheses and argument placeholders for required arguments.
>
> [image: dart.completeFunctionCalls]

Comment: am new in vscode can you please give guide to accomplish the fix

Comment: This setting is not yet available in the Flutter stable channel, so if you're using Stable and really need this, you would be better disabling LSP for now. Open your VS Code user settings and search for "preview lsp" and untick it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help